# Postgres Hierarchical Aggregation at each node level

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation, hierarchical-data

I have the following table structure in postgres

| id | parent_id | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1000 |
| 2 | 1 | 1000 |
| 3 | 1 | 1000 |
| 4 | 2 | 1000 |
| 5 | 2 | 1000 |
| 6 | 3 | 1000 |
| 7 | 3 | 1000 |
| 8 | 4 | 1000 |

I would like to write a query which gives me the following output ( aggregation at each node level )

| id | parent_id | balance | total_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1000 | 8000 |
| 2 | 1 | 1000 | 4000 |
| 3 | 1 | 1000 | 3000 |
| 4 | 2 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 5 | 2 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 6 | 3 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 7 | 3 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 8 | 4 | 1000 | 1000 |

I already tried query but the output for this is not as I expected

| d | parent_id | balance | total_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 3 | 1 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 4 | 2 | 1000 | 3000 |
| 5 | 2 | 1000 | 3000 |
| 6 | 3 | 1000 | 3000 |
| 7 | 3 | 1000 | 3000 |
| 8 | 4 | 1000 | 4000 |

Eg:- id 1 should have an aggregated value of 8000 ( id 2 aggregate (4000) + id 3 aggregate (3000) + id 1 (1000)

Comment: Please share your attempt, even if it is not working.

Comment: Could you explain how you get `4000` for id `2` & `3000` for id `3` ... ?

Comment: @SelVazi, thanks for commenting my poor answer.

Comment: @SelVazi for 3 is 3000, because 6 and 7 both have 1000 and their parent is 3. So sum came from 3,6,7 = 3000

Answer (score 1):

You must use recursive CTE.

Try this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE sum_recursive AS (
    SELECT id, balance, id as parent_id
    FROM your_table 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.id, t.balance, sr.parent_id
    FROM your_table AS t
    JOIN sum_recursive sr ON sr.id = t.parent_id
)
SELECT parent_id, SUM(balance) as total_balance
FROM sum_recursive
GROUP BY parent_id;
```

Here is fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cRk7bKEZX5vYqTSauqWXWa/0